# Facebook Sign in on Ionic - what is the recommended plugin or capacitor component for mobile apps, and what FB SDK does it use?

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I have an old app that uses cordova-plugin-facebook4, but Facebook complains that the SDK is old. I tried re-installing with the newest cordova-plugin-facebook4 but the SDK that is being fetched by the coco pod is still rather old.

1. What is the current best way to sign in via Facebook on Ionic apps?
2. Does it have a new FB SDK (which version for Android and iOS)?
3. Is there a way to keep the SDK in cordova-plugin-facebook4 - up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect. This is the active fork of cordova-plugin-facebook4 which was deprecated, and it uses v8 of the Facebook SDK on both Android and iOS.

Comment: Thanks Noah. Yes, it has (finally) been updated recently.